# PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to

Tags: php

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Account::updateUser() must
>   be an instance of  , string given, called in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myPage/beta/Includes/includes.php
>   on line 27 and defined in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myPage/beta/classes/Account.php
>   on line 214

Line 27:

```
$Account->updateUser($_SESSION["username"], $_POST["password_check"], $_POST["pw1"], $_POST["pw2"]);
```

Line 214:

```
public function updateUser($session, $password_check, $pw, $pw2){
```

How may I fix this? I've tried to rewrite the code multiple times, and tried to change everything on line 214 and below. Also tried to change some of line 27, cannot find the problem and have googled for a long time.

Comment: `must be an instance of , `... of what?

Comment: Idk, it's just like that

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an invisible character (something like an unbreakable space, or some other invisible utf8 char) in your function declaration and php think it's [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). You could delete the line and rewrite it. I thnik the probleme is here because `must be an instance of ,` means php want a variable of type "".

Delete and rewrite the function declaration (no copy/paste)

Comment: How so you mean? Is there a " " somewhere?

Comment: There is (i'm almost sure) a single character that is no displayed (because of the font, or the "nature" of character). Did you tried what I wrote?

Comment: Also, there's other functions like that one which works fine